# How runtime polymorphism work if retention policy of override is source

Tags: java, annotations, polymorphism, overriding

I know that Overriding a method from super class is nothing but `runtime` polymorphism.

Oracle docs says that `@Override` annotation uses `@Retention(value=SOURCE)`. That means that `@Override` annotation will be removed as we compile the code.

So my question here is, how would `runtime` polymorphism work actually. Does it has to do anything at compile time? What **actually** happens here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: depends on which class instance is created... nothing to do with annotations

Comment: Then why would we use it at first place?  @sidgate

Comment: you don't have to use it. you can still override a method without using the annotation. it is just for compile time check

Comment: If you annotate with @Override, you've asserted to the compiler that it was your intent to override a superclass method. The compiler can then warn you if you failed to give use the correct  method signature and thus did not, in fact, override the super's method.  And if you write a method that happens (possibly accidentally) to overrides a super method, but **don't** add `@Override`, you'll get warned about that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Override is an annotation that will fail the compile phase if it is added to a method that is not an override. It has no utility after the compile phase, hence the retention policy. Polimorphism happens at runtime and is independent of the override annotation.